# Reading accented characters (á) C# UTF-8 / Windows 1252

Tags: c#, utf-8, windows-1252

I am trying to read a file that has some letters that aren't showing up correctly when I am trying to convert the file to XMl. The letters come up as blocks when I open them in notepad++, but in the original document they are correct. An example letter is á.

I am using UTF-8 to encode the file so it should be covered in that but it isn't for some reason. If I change it to windows 1252 then it shows the character correctly.

Why is it not available in UTF-8 encoding but is in Windows 1252?

If you need anymore information then just ask, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Notepad++ has options (under the `Encoding` menu) to change the way a file is decoded. Have you tried changing those options?

Comment: You: _I am using UTF-8 to encode the file_ How? You should show us. Clearly UTF-8 can be used with any Unicode character, including `á`, and in my experience Notepad++ will guess the encoding, so you must have a mistake in your encoding?

Comment: Yes what is really strange is the original document is in UTF-8 and displays the character it is only when I read the original file and convert it to xml using C# that it then doesn't work in UTF8 anymore but does if I do it in Windows 1252.

Comment: Does that `á` look correct in the debugger if you debug your C#? Either you read the original file with a wrong decoding, or you write the new file with a wrong encoding, I would say. Show us your code.

Comment: Ok thanks, I will do that when I can.